# How to convert mat file to numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy

I want to convert a mat file with size 600 by 600 to numpy array and I got this error "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'" I am wondering how can I fix it.

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.io as sio
    test = sio.loadmat('Y7.mat')
    data=np.zeros((600,600))
    data[:,:]=test
```

Comment: Read the `loadmat` docs more carefully.  It produces a dictionary containing arrays.  It is not an array itself.

Comment: Then, how can I convert mat file to numpy array? I tried all the solutions in stack overflow and none of them worked for me.

Comment: You don't convert it. You find desired array in the loaded dictionary. Did you read the docs?? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [240]: from scipy.io import loadmat
```

Using a test mat file that I have from past SO questions:

```
In [241]: loadmat('test.mat')                                                                 
Out[241]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sat Mar 21 20:09:30 2020',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'x': array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])}
```

`loadmat` has given me a dictionary (see the {}?). This happens to have one array, with key 'x'.  So I just access it with standard dictionary indexing:

```
In [242]: _['x']                                                                              
Out[242]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```

`x` was a variable in the MATLAB session that saved this file.

I don't know anything about what's on your file.  `print(list(data.keys()))` can be used to see those keys/variable names.

I tried to get you to look at the `loadmat` docs, and see that it:

```
Returns
    mat_dictdict
        dictionary with variable names as keys, and loaded matrices as values.
```

Comment: The key and variable of my file ['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'Ar'] are  Array of float32 , list, bytes, str. Since the mat file version is 7.3 Maltab files I need a HDF5 python library to read MATLAB 7.3 format mat files.  I used the solution at this link htps://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python but it raised with this error : Unable to open file (file signature not found)

Comment: did you try `data['Ar']`?

Comment: If `loadmat` did not raise an error, and gave you a `dict`, then this is a valid pre-HDF5 file.  You just have to use the right `key` to access the desired array.

Comment: The loadmat did nor raised with an error. How can I use the right key in below code?f = h5py.File('Y7.mat','r')
data = f.get('data/variable1')
data = np.array(data)

Comment: I used the hdf5storage.write command to save it as h5 file and then I compress it to npz file with command np.savez_compressed. The size reduced from 400 kb to 1 kb!  I am not sure whether  all the data are existed in the npz file or not. The reason I am doing all this stuff is that my mat file size is about 600 kb and I want to save it as npz to reduce the data size to feed 100000 of those to my CNN code.

Comment: I'm confused.  Did you get the original `loadmat` to work, or not?  Did my advise on how to access the value from the dictionary work?  Or is this a completely new file?

Comment: Yes, the original loadmat worked but I your advise on how to access the values did not work. Actually, I changed my approach to reach the goal as I described on previous comment. However, I don not know how to decompress the npz file.