# Converting .mat file to numpy array

Tags: python, keras, scipy, mat

I was trying to upload my dataset to python by following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274746/how-to-convert-mat-file-to-numpy-array). Yet my code gives error. You can see the code and the error in image. Can you guys help me to fix it?

[image: Code&error]

Comment: why don't you just try `pref_mat['a']`?

Comment: I am kinda new to python so just tried to apply what i read. Apart from that your suggestion worked just fine. Thank you

Comment: Okay. Great. I have also  added an answer. It would be nice if you could accept and upvote that so that others can be see it as well. That's just a tradition in stackoverflow.

Comment: I was trying find a way to turn question status to solved but only after refreshing the page i saw your answer (i didn't know that i can't point a comment as an answer so was trying to figure out how can i turn it to answer). Sorry for delay

Comment: No problem. Good luck and Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `pref_mat['a']`. Here is an example reproducing the error:

```
>>>from scipy.io import loadmat
>>> pref_mat = loadmat('global.mat')
>>>_['global_']
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
>>> pref_mat['global_']
array([[1, 3, 5]], dtype=uint8)
```